# canceled status blocking font download

Tags: http, fonts, request-cancelling

I have a page with some text that has been given a font-family of constitution:

[image]

This font was downloaded from a foundary and is defined for the page with an @font-face:
[image]

When the page renders, the browser goes out for the font but the request is blocked by a cancel and the text doesn't get the font-family applied:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be causing this cancel?  This used to work, and I can't imagine what I did or what happened to break it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any error reported in console? Is this `Constitution.ttf` deployed in a different domain?

Comment: Yes! The error is: "Access to Font at https://example.com/fonts/Constitution.ttf from `http://example.com` has been blocked by CORS policy. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values: `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, but only one is allowed. `http://example.com` is, therefore not allowed access."  Thank  you!  What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: There should be only one `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with only one origin (or wildcard sign). I guess this is caused by accidentally add additional `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server configuration. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header expect only one origin, or a wildcard (`*`).

The error you mentioned in the question's comment ("The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values ... but only one is allowed") clearly indicates that there are multiple values in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, or there are multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

To fix the issue, there should be only one `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, with only one origin value.

---

As mentioned in the question: "This used to work". I guess this issue is caused by accidentally add additional `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server configuration.

---

For reference, please check the W3C [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/#access-control-allow-origin):

> A resource can have **one** Access-Control-Allow-Origin header defined. The header must match the following ABNF:
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ":" ascii-origin | "*"
>
> ascii-origin                = ASCII serialization of **an origin**

Comment: I fixed this with a mod_rewrite to send non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS.  But I'm curuous how I would fix it if I wanted to allow HTTP and HTTPS access. I've never specified an Accedd-Control-Allow-Origin header in the code so how did this get set, and how can I modify it?  Thanks

Comment: @Steve I guess `http://example.com` host the webpage. In that case, you only need to put `https://example.com` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If  `https://example.com` host the webpage, then put `http://example.com` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Otherwise, just use `*`.

Comment: If you've never specified `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` manually, my guess is: it is set by some module/plugin...

Answer (score 1):

1. Put this inside your **virtual host** definition or `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   <FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|ttc)$">
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
       Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
2. Restart Apache web server
3. Refresh the page multiple times (Hard Refresh)